# Update widget position onTap

Tags: flutter

I have a stack widget that holds a background `image` and a `textField` widgets , I want the user to be able to change the position of the text `onTap`, I know how to get point details of the tap , but I don't know how to pass this information to textField to update its position

Edit: that's what I did so far, it works only to right or right, then it just disappears!! I think the problem in the coordinate details and use of `stack` and `positioned` widgets , but can't figure out how to fix it

```
Stack(children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child: Card(
                        child: (finalsd == null)
                            ? Image.file(File(_image.path))
                            : Image.file(File(finalsd!.path))))),
            Positioned(
              top: 25,
              left: 50,
              child: Visibility(
                visible: caption_vis,
                child: GestureDetector(
                    onTapDown: (details) {
                      setState(() {
                        positionHeight = details.localPosition.dx;
                        positionWidth = details.localPosition.dy;
                        print(positionWidth);
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: positionHeight,
                      width: positionWidth,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: _controller,
                        focusNode: myFocusNode,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        ),
                        onSubmitted: (String value) async {
                          //Your Code
                        },
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
            )
          ])
```

Comment: give us a Reproducible Example

Comment: please check my update

Answer (score 0):

You can resize it by wrapping it with a TextField Container and updating the container height and width when the trigger you want occurs.

```
 double? positionHeight = 0;
  double? positionWidth = 0;

GestureDetector(
        onTapDown: (details) {
          setState(() {
            positionHeight = 100;
            positionWidth = 100;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          height: positionHeight,
          width: positionWidth,
          child: TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            focusNode:myFocusNode ,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
              enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
              disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            ),
            onSubmitted: (String value) async {
              //Your Code
            },
          ),
        )),
```

If you only want to position, not resize, you can set the Padding value this way.

```
EdgeInsetsGeometry textFieldPadding = EdgeInsets.all(8.0);
    
   GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (details) {
        setState(() {
          textFieldPadding = const EdgeInsets.all(8.0);
          textFieldPadding = EdgeInsets.zero;
          textFieldPadding = EdgeInsetsGeometry.infinity;
          textFieldPadding =
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10);
        });
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: textFieldPadding,
        child: TextField(
          controller: _controller,
          focusNode:myFocusNode ,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          ),
          onSubmitted: (String value) async {
            //Your Code
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks , I think I get it , but shouldn't we replace positionHeight & width with `details` instead of a hard-coded number!

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand what you mean, can you give a little more detail?